# Dynamic Columns in the form of a table crystal report visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal report in which i want to show some columns in the form of table rows.
no. of rows in display table that is actually the columns in database table depends on registration date. anyone here to help me out how to do that.. so far have done this.. Sample Report is attached ..
i just want to that all the empty rows should not be displayed on the report

[image: Sample Output of the report]

Comment: If each row is based on a separate column and you have sub-sectioned report for each such row then sub-sections can be suppressed using formulas comparing column values. If it's not so then post more details about report design, a preview of designer would be more helpful.

Comment: Every row in registration fee column of the picture is a saperate column in database?